# need explanation on math calculation done by using c

Tags: c

I found following code on c

```
 #include<stdio.h> 
 int main(){
     int a;
     a=015 + 0x71 +5;
     printf("%d",a);
     return 0;
     }
```

when i compile it, it gives 131 as the answer. but i am not able find out how it is happening

Comment: octal, hexadecimal, decimal. Look that up!

Comment: `015 + 0x71 +5` has numbers represented in three different bases. All it's missing is a binary literal.

Comment: @Shawn But of course there are no binary literals in Standard C.

Comment: 8+5+7*16+1+5 = 131

Comment: What value ***would*** you have expected?  ***Why?***

Comment: @SteveSummit Could have sworn binary literals had been lifted from C++ for C2X, but looks like they haven't.

Comment: @Shawn There are some compilers that add it as a compiler extension, but it is not a part of the C standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, a number starting with `0` is in octal (base 8), and a number starting with `0x` is in hexadecimal (base 16).

`015 + 0x71 + 5` is 15<sub>8</sub> + 71<sub>16</sub> + 5 = (1•8 + 5) + (7•16 + 1) + 5 = 13 + 113 + 5 = 131.

Answer (score 1):

Octal `015` is base-10 value `13`
Hex value `0x71` is base-10 value `113`
`5` is base-10.

Add together `13 + 113 + 5`, and you get `131`